# Why won't my method overwrites work every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm working with Rails 2.3.5. What I want is for Ruby modules in `"#{Rails.root}/lib/extensions"` to be loaded at app startup and included into controllers and/or models. That's easily done by putting code similar to the following at the bottom of my `environment.rb`:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/extensions/*.rb"].each do |file|
    ...... 
    AController.send(:require, file)
    AController.send(:include, constant_of_module_in_file)
end
```

That works. I can test it. My module gets included. In some of these modules I do this:

```
def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval { ... overwrite some methods ... }
end
```

When I test this code with `scripts/console` I get what I want: my overwriting method is called whenever I call the method on an instance of AController. Not the case when I run the webapp and test the code that should run my overwrites. Instead a funny thing happens: on the first request I get what I expect (the overwrite behavior), but subsequent requests run the method I'm trying to overwrite! **Why is that??**

I've seen behavior like this before, and it's usually because of the class reloading that happens in the development environment. In this case, however, `config.cache_classes` and `config.action_controller.perform_caching` are both `false`.

Any light shed on this behavior is helpful. I've tried all kinds of metaprogramming using `#extend`, `#alias_method_chain`, class redefinitions, etc. but the behavior is always the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want your caching config to be `true` in this case, no?  If they're `false`, then your classes _will_ get reloaded, but without running the one-shot code from environment.rb...

Comment: Doh! You're right, Xavier. That was it. My oversight. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1):

If `cache_classes` is false, your classes are unloaded and reloaded on every request (because they are not cached). That's where you shoot yourself in the foot with your `environment.rb`.

If you just require the files and include the modules you want in the class, your overwrites are being applied every time:

```
require file
class AController < ApplicationController
  include constant_of_module_in_file
end
```

**Edit:** Credit goes to Xavier Holt, I only saw his comment after posting the answer!